# PyCharm keymap: altered copy and cut commands

Tags: ide, pycharm, keymaps

I was looking for a way to disable the `Copy` and `Cut` commands usual behavior alteration: **applying to current line** instead of doing nothing when no selection is active.

I'm regularly caught with my emacs user reflex: `Ctrl+X, Ctrl+S` ...
which deletes current line before saving the file  !!

I know there is an emacs keymap, but ...I'd prefer not (for instance no reference card for alternate keymaps).

For now the best I could do was to *remove* `Ctrl+X` and `Ctrl+C` shortcuts, and try to get used to their alternate mappings: `Ctrl+Insert` and `Shift-Delete`.

Any better ideas ?

Comment: There's no time limit on "when to edit a post". Then, your 1st sentence already is a question only phrased without a question mark (the last sentence doesn't add anything, and it's common practice to remove it). Lastly, using the ide tag with the pycharm tag is redundant, (no one uses the 2 tags together) because pycharm is obviously an IDE...So, these were my criteria in editing. But hey, if you don't like the edit and want to roll-back the edit no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Slash to activate the "Maintenance" menu, select "Registry", enable the `editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection` option.